# Large NSNumber to NSString conversion

Tags: ios, objective-c

I really can't figure out how to convert large NSNumber to NSString (4h googling not solved my problem and tried all suggested solutions - stringValue, NSNumberFormatter, NSDecimalNumber).

Currently I converting in this way:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%llu", [largeNumber unsignedLongLongValue]];
```

All works fine with small numbers but with larger I get wrong strings :( Example: Input number is 10202713632509569, but returned string is 10202713632509568. How to convert NSNumber to NSString in proper way?

I get NSNumber from JSON response with AFNetworking framework.

My JSON:

```
{
    "author": {
        "name": "Open Graph Test User",
        "social_type": "facebook",
        "id": 10202713632509569
    }
}
```

My code:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager new];
manager.responseSerializer             = [AFJSONResponseSerializer new];

[manager GET:@"/api/author"
  parameters:nil
     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
         NSNumber *largeNumber = responseObject[@"author"][@"social_id"];
         // ...
         NSString *callPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/profile/%@/%@", _userSocialType, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%llu", [largeNumber unsignedLongLongValue]]];
         // ...
     }
     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         // ...
     }
  }];
```

Comment: When you try it with 'largeNumber.stringValue', what are you getting?

Comment: I am getting this: 1.020271363250957e+16

Comment: What is the purpose of storing this large number as a number and not directly as a string? Can you break the number into an Upper and Lower subset where they both are a power of 10 (only necessary for calculations).

Comment: I get NSNumber from JSON response and need string representation of this number for URL creation.

Comment: @urfin Perhaps you run into the problem where the JSON parser is storing your number as floating-point rather than as an integer.

Comment: Have you tried `NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];     
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle]; // adjust this
NSString *formattedOutput = [formatter stringFromNumber:yourDecimalNumber];` to get rid of scientific notation?

Comment: Isn't JSON already text, and therefore a string?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I am using AFJSONRequestSerializer from AFNetworking

Comment: @Cole Yes, I tried this with NSNumberFormatterNoStyle (result: 10202713632509600 - incorrect) and NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle (result: 10,202,713,632,509,600 - incorrect)

Comment: @Matt No, in JSON I have raw number

Comment: Show us how you create the `largeNumber`! And no, technically you have the value as string, since the json is basically a string.

Comment: @luk2302 yes, he does, but that's not terribly useful since the JSON parser converts it to a number.

Comment: @luk2302 This is my JSON response: http://pastebin.com/9FShpcHp. I am not creating largeNumber manually - I am using AFNetworking framework for JSON handling

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant just saying "technichally"...

Comment: Show us your **code**. You are referencing `largeNumber`, where does it come from? is it a simplification, don't over-simplificate things because you might remove the useful information.

Comment: @luk2302 This is my code - http://pastebin.com/JemWXXr8

Comment: Your NSNumber is in `double` format, and only contains 16 decimal digits of precision.  You must use NSDecimalNumber or int64 to get higher precision.

Comment: @HotLicks but the problem is he doesn't get to control that. It's the JSON parser that is outputting a double.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant - He should check whether the parser is indeed returning a NSDecimalNumber, and, if so, use an alternate method to extract it's value.  (I hassled with this scenario quite a bit, and NSJSONSerialization does some odd but usually unwindable conversions to maintain significance for numbers in this range.)